# cleaning a html code snippet not an entire doc with htmlcleaner

Tags: htmlcleaner

i am using org.htmlcleaner

I am adding some user generated html and would like to clean it.
but when i do:

```
String signature  = "<div>Some sig</div>
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
signatureTagNode = cleaner.clean( signature );
SimpleHtmlSerializer htmlSerializer = new SimpleHtmlSerializer(props);
String cleanedHTML = htmlSerializer.getAsString( signatureTagNode );
```

The cleanedHTML has the body and html tags added. Is there a flag or property that does not add these. I could not find them here http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/parameters.php#transform

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before calling your serializer:

`props.setOmitHtmlEnvelope(true);`